# Can't login on server using ssh [Too many authentication failures]

Tags: linux, ssh, unix, authentication, ssh-keys

I'm not able to login in the server. I keep getting this error:

`Received disconnect from 128.238.182.77: 2: Too many authentication failures for bmpasini`

It happened to me before and I solved by using `-o PubkeyAuthentication=no`, then I logged in and added my public key to the `authenticated_keys` file. Everything was working fine until this morning, but now I keep getting this error.

I tried using `IdentitiesOnly=yes` too, but no luck. Also tried `ssh-add -D` and didn't work.

Also, every time I try to login it asks me for a password even though I specify the private key using `-i ~/.ssh/gray17`.

Here's what I get when I run it with verbose:

```
debug1: Reading configuration data /Users/brunomacedo/.ssh/config
debug1: /Users/brunomacedo/.ssh/config line 13: Applying options for gray17
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh_config line 20: Applying options for *
debug1: /etc/ssh_config line 102: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to gray17.poly.edu [128.238.182.77] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /Users/brunomacedo/.ssh/gray17 type 1
debug1: identity file /Users/brunomacedo/.ssh/gray17-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.2
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_5.3
debug1: match: OpenSSH_5.3 pat OpenSSH_5*
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST(1024<1024<8192) sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_INIT sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: RSA ef:bf:c0:70:d0:bb:93:71:ab:c2:63:75:e6:c2:ea:85
debug1: Host 'gray17.poly.edu' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /Users/brunomacedo/.ssh/known_hosts:10
debug1: ssh_rsa_verify: signature correct
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: Roaming not allowed by server
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /Users/brunomacedo/.ssh/gray17
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Next authentication method: password
bmpasini@gray17.poly.edu's password:
```

If I try to type my password it fails:

`Received disconnect from 128.238.182.77: 2: Too many authentication failures for bmpasini`

Even though I'm sure my password is correct.

Anyone knows what is going on?

Comment: when you imput the password whats is shell's output?

Comment: `Received disconnect from 128.238.182.77: 2: Too many authentication failures for bmpasini`